# Xamarin Forms Error Ispassword

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10,30,10,10" Spacing="10">
        <Label Text="Protected Animal"
               Font="30"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Text="Ingresar al Sistema"                 
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="waitActivityIndicator"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Text="Usuario"                
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Entry x:Name="userEntry"
                Placeholder="Ingresar Usuario"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Text="Clave"                
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry"
                Placeholder="Ingresar clave"
                Ispassword="true"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Button x:Name="enterButton"
            Text="Ingresar"
            BackgroundColor="Navy"
            TextColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Me marca error en lo siguiente:

```
    <Label Text="Clave"                
           HorizontalOptions="Start"
           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry"
            Placeholder="Ingresar clave"
            Ispassword="True"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

Este es el mensaje de error **Excepción no controlada**:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Posición 31:21. No se puede
>   asignar la propiedad "Ispassword": La propiedad no existe, o no es
>   asignable, o no coincide entre el valor y la propiedad

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ProyectoNoveno
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new ProyectoNoveno.MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y el código de tu backend?

Comment: el solo fronted, puro diseño no hay backend funciona cuando le quito  <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry"
            Placeholder="Ingresar clave"
            Ispassword="True"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación oficial https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Entry/

Hay una diferencia entre Ispassword e IsPassword : una mayúscula

```
 <Label Text="Clave"                
           HorizontalOptions="Start"
           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry"
            Placeholder="Ingresar clave"
            IsPassword="True"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

Comment: Gracias ese era el error :)

Comment: de nada bro :D bienvenido a SOes!